# Angular Custom FN in data definition

Tags: angular, components

I can set a fn handler to my component in parent by emit event from output variable

parent.html

```
<myEl (onClick)="handleClick()" />
```

myElComponent.ts

```
  @Output() onClick: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  ...

  onClick() {
    this.onClick.emit();
  }
```

But I need set a FN in data definition

parent.html

```
<myEl [cols] ="cols" [rows]="rows" />
```

parent.ts

```
cols: codDef[]= [{
        dataKey: 'flag',
        dataKeyFn: handleFlagClick  //<<<<<<<<<<<
      }{
        dataKey: 'score',
        dataKeyFn: handleScoreClick  //<<<<<<<<<<<
      }]

rows = [{flag:1, score:10},{flag:2, score:9}....{flag:10, score:1}]
```

How I can get/set my handleCustonFn in child component to send a emiter?

I'm creating a component to show many panels and each panel can raise event a custom FN in parent depending on dataKeyFn set. The handleFn will be receive row (flag or score value depending witch panel was clicked) and col (definition of this row). Basicaly  I need convert a string to Output variable value but for each value from my rows array

Comment: just call the event emitter inside the dataKeyFn, handleFlagClick

Comment: handleFlagClick dont exist in childComponent , only in parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining the colDef you can add `.bind(this)` which will make the function you bind, execute with the scope where it was set ( here it will be the parent )

To Sum up, use `bind` to bind the parent scope to the function of colDef, now even if its executed in the child component, it can access the parent eventEmitter.

```
      cols: codDef[]= [{
        dataKey: 'flag',
        dataKeyFn: handleFlagClick.bind(this)  //<<<<<<<<<<<
      }{
        dataKey: 'score',
        dataKeyFn: handleScoreClick.bind(this)  //<<<<<<<<<<<
      }]
```

Comment: tks, Work wonderfull !!!     (click)="col?.dataKeyFn!(col, row)"   call my parent fn :)